# Why does Android require a Context to access a resource?

Tags: android

I get why Android requires you to pass a Context object when trying to get a view for example, show a Toast, etc.

However, I don't really get the point for requiring it to access resources that could be shared by different Contexts in your application.

I several times found myself trying to access a resource from a utility class using a static method or something along those lines, and find it pretty annoying to require a passing of a Context param.

I fail to see where something could go south with this.

Comment: When you required to get or access resource out side from activity then you required context reference of current activity.

Comment: the context of the activity is like the interface of the class

Comment: "the context of the activity is like the interface of the class"?? I fail to understand that.

Comment: Ok. WHat I'd like to know is why does Android require it. Why can't any  class that is running within your app access for example any String resource ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) :

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
> is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
> system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
> classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
> launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

In clear, the context is the middleman between the telephone resource, and your code. And it seems logical, that you cannot access to this from everywhere.

The reason you can only access to Context in Activity and Application classes, is because both derives from Context :

> java.lang.Object
>
> ```
> ↳ android.content.Context
>
>   ↳ android.content.ContextWrapper
>
>       ↳ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
>
>           ↳ android.app.Activity
> ```

Comment: It may have been a good idea at some point, but a god object living inside superobjects called for bad practices since day 1.

Comment: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: I get that, I just don't get why you can't access your app's resources from any class that is running in a thread that was started by your app, without passing a Context object around

Comment: Actually, Context is only available in your Activity classes right (and Application) ? The reason you can only use inside, is because Activity and Application both derives from Context. See edited answer.

Comment: But why does Android need it ? What can the Context give that Android can not possibly infer ?. It could realize that you are calling it from within a certain app, and give you access to those local resources, the same way you can access global resources with Resources.getSystem(). I don't get the problem in having something like Resources.getLocal()

Answer (score 1):

Extend Application class by your own `public class MyApp extends Application` and  register `MyApp` in your manifest and have `MyApp` something like this:

```
class MyApp extends Application {
...
private static ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public static void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  context = this;
}

public static String string(int resId) {
   return context.getString(resId);
}

}
```

Then you can do `MyApp.string(R.id.mystring)` from everywhere. You can do the same for other resource types.

You can also do `(MyApp)getApplication()` if you prefer so.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answer the question "Why does Android require a Context to access a resource?", it's simply a workaround. Also, extending `Application` should only be done in specific cases where it's absolutely necessary - in general it should only be used for maintaining global state and not as a springboard to a `Context` instance. Also, the application `Context` has limitations so following your design example may not work in certain situations.

Comment: @Squonk "extending Application should only be done in specific cases where it's absolutely necessary" - could you, please, elaborate why?

As to answering the original question I maintain this does answer exactly it.

Comment: I actually do use this workaround, but only to access resources. What I actually want to know is the reason why a context is required.

Comment: @Mate Because those API functions take a context as a parameter..

Comment: That's my question! Why would Android require that ? Accessing the resources of an Application from within any Activity or Service would yield the same results. I don't see the point in requiring a Context.